# Why is ostringstream faster than ofstream

Tags: c++, filestream, iostream

To write many piece of data to file, I have 2 approaches:

1. Write to ofstream one by one directly

   ```
   ofstream file("c:\\test.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
   {
       file << data[i];
   }
   ```
2. Write to istringstream  first, and then write to ofstream at once

   ```
   ostringstream strstream;
   for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
   {
       strstream << data[i];
   }
   ofstream file("c:\\test.txt");
   file << strstream.str();
   ```

Not surprisingly, the second approach is faster, in fact, it is 4 times faster than the first approach on my HP7800 machine.

But why? I know ofstream is using filebuf inside, and ostringstream is using stringbuf - as a buffer they should all reside in memory thus should have no difference.

What is the difference under the hood?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you using `std::endl` a lot instead of `'\n'`? `std::endl` does two things: it inserts a `'\n'` into the stream and then ***flushes the buffer to disk***. I've seen code talking a severe performance hit by doing so. (The code ran 5-10 times faster after that was fixed.)
Flushing to a string buffer will be much faster than flushing to the disk, so that would explain your findings.

If that's not the case you might consider is increasing the buffer size:

```
const std::size_t buf_size = 32768;
char my_buffer[buf_size];
ofstream file("c:\\test.txt");
file.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(my_buffer, buf_size);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    file << data[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is caused by the frequent flush by appending **std::endl**. And it turns out that both filebuf and stringbuf can grow its memory buffer size when it is not enough. see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/filebuf/overflow/)

Comment: Now I am thinking of why it provide us with a **pubsetbuf** to set buffer, - maybe it is used when we already have some content in the memory, instead of appending it to streambuf - we just let streambuf point to it.

Comment: @lzprgmr: 1) So my first assumption was right. Good. 2) Stream buffers usually ___do not grow___ their buffers, instead they ___flush to the device___ on overflow. String stream buffer is an exception to this, since its "device" ___is___ an in-memory buffer (from which you can obtain the string). 3) `pubsetbuf()` can be used when you know more about the environment/device. You can then provide the stream with a buffer of whatever size you consider good. I'm not sure if there's a use case beyond providing a ___custom-sized___ buffer.

Comment: I did a test, and the filebuf will be forced to flush if size of the buffer is not enough - not keep on growing like stringbuf does.

Comment: @lzprgmr: Which I believe is what I wrote.

Comment: Wow, huge speed increase from switching endl to "\n" thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Disk is slow. Many small writes are more expensive than one large.

Comment: But that should be avoided by buffering.

Comment: ofstream will not buffer indefinitely, it will write whenever the internal buffer reaches a threshold.

Comment: do you know what the threshold is? is there any reference. From [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/filebuf/overflow/) api description, it seems it will grow the memory if not enough.

Comment: @lzprgmr: Sorry, no idea, I believe this is implementation dependent. sbi's answer shows how to change it though.

Answer (score 2):

It can be implementation issue with specific OS.
Also I guess the ofstream buffer(buflen) is smaller than 10000, a typical value of which is 4095. So try running with i<4096 and the response time should be quite same!

The reason why it's faster in the second case:

In the first case when the buffer is full ( buflen=4095bytes) it is written to disk. So for i<10000 it'd have caused it to be flushed 3 times.

While in the second case, all data is first prepared in the RAM and in one go flushed to the harddisk. So two flushes have been saved!